# What is the proper way to post an MCVE in frameworks like Django?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

I think most people would not want someone to post their entire Django project into a question, but there's really no way to post an isolated piece of a Django project that someone else can copy into their IDE and run. Django only works if you have all the proper files in order.

Should you just post whatever code is necessary to understand the problem?

Comment: [They seem to get the hang of it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+isaccepted%3Atrue)

Comment: I haven't used Django but while you might have to list what files/libraries you've included, you don't have to have the actual files in the question. Basic stuff that any Django project would require to be runnable doesn't need to be included either. For example, in many cases an HTML question won't need to include the `head` in its MVCE.

Comment: I don't know diddly about Django, but you might be interested in the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340798/how-to-create-a-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example-for-c-ui-related-ques/340844#340844).

Comment: I would copy the error. The minimum amount of the block, and the minimum amount of model if required or used. You can decern what is needed to find a solution if it's not enough the community should let you know. For those that are not familiar with MCVE. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean.