# What does MCVE mean?

Tags: support, minimal-reproducible-example, terminology

I did a search for related questions and [found this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340874/true-meaning-of-mcve).

However that's not the same thing and doesn't answer what ***MCVE actually stands for***.

What does it mean in the context of these questions?

1. [Can we introduce the concept of a MCVE to people before they even have a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366974/can-we-introduce-the-concept-of-a-mcve-to-people-before-they-even-have-a-questio)
2. [MCVE for Not Being Very Welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366867/mcve-for-not-being-very-welcoming)

Comment: This was closed as "can not be reproduced", ***If you don't know what it means, you need to ask someone.***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is not enough? [mcve] is a magic markdown link that will auto create the link to this page on SO

Comment: Hmm, glad we added that - didn't know it was there until now.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes here. The user did research- They tried to find the answer themselves. They posted what they found. The question is clear- They're trying to understand an acronym they've seen thrown around the past few days. The question is _useful_ because plenty of newer users are going to be unfamiliar with this term. The help center is not always the most obvious place to look for something like the definition of an acronym, and once you've been here a while, it can be a little hard to remember there is a help center, let alone _find_ it.

Comment: @Stargateur Not everyone knows about the magic links, and once you've been here a while, the help center can be a little difficult to find. And really, the help center is _not_ where I would think to find the definition of an acronym if I was a newer user or I was seeing it for the first time.

Comment: Interestingly: My dyslexic brain always sees "MVCE" - I wonder how many people are like "_BUT I'M NOT USING MVC!_"

Comment: @Kendra Did they really do research though? Almost always step 1 of any research is to Google/Bing/Duck Duck Go it. On all three of those search engines, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the first result. If a user is incapable of performing that research, then they'll be incapable of finding this question as well, and therefore it's not useful to future people who don't know what MCVE is.

Comment: @mason I don't use Bing or DuckDuckGo, but Google doesn't always return the same results for the same search for different people. Just as an FYI. I didn't say they couldn't have found the answer on their own, but they have included a question they found with their own search. Clearly, they did research. If it's not good enough research for you, that's fine, but they _did_ search.

Comment: @Kendra Failing to do a web search is definitely not good enough research. That's the absolute minimum a user should do, when researching any issue ever. Search engines may not always return the same results in the same order, but they're good enough that a page explaining this information would have been one of the first few hits.

Comment: I searched Google for the meaning first but I wasn't seeing the results I'm not seeing from the links people are pasting in. I suspect I either spelt it wrong or the index that's being returned has changed. Either way, the answers provided are detailed and thorough so we're all winners today.

Comment: @mason The [top rated question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5255018), has 21k votes, and a lot of assorted google answers. is that question not worthy of this site? - you could say the same about the rest of the top rated questions here. Are all of those unworthy? Can you please explain the distinction between those questions and this one?

Comment: @MichaelB Asking about concepts is very different from asking about a dictionary definition. Concepts need explanation. Asking "what does MCVE stand for?" would be a very different question than "How can I create a MCVE?" One is easy to Google and find the documentation, the other might require looking at multiple examples that documentation wouldn't necessarily cover.

Comment: @TimPost (I write this knowing you've written an answer, and having a lot of respect for your views here) Isn't your first comment a very prime example of SO not being very welcoming? I get that there's probably humour there, but if I've just googled MCVE, and landed here, and notice that a moderator is responding like that, that is very much going to reenforce my view that this place isn't welcoming.

Comment: @mason the sixth top rated question asks what the yield keyword does. I imagine that is equally easy to find documentation for. I'm really not trying to be argumentative here, but there are multiple standards going on. To me this is a viable question, and it deserves (and has) an answer. telling people to google isn't very welcoming.

Comment: @MichaelB There are a lot of useless highly upvoted questions that should be removed. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for actual research. If that research is too difficult, then sure, ask a question. This particular case, that research was not adequately done. I don't care if you don't feel that it's welcoming - proper research wasn't done and it deserved a downvote in my opinion. I've offered an explanation for why I downvoted, which I expect explains quite a few of the others, and now I'm being told that I'm not welcoming because of it. No wonder experienced users are getting frustrated!

Comment: @mason it is a place of research. The site is a Q&A site, the very nature of it is research and determining what level accounts for acceptable or not is as one flag puts it 'primarily opinion based'. I did research, besides, after a while this questions has gotten a lot of attention and arguably is now much more likely to appear in searches for when other people have the same issue. This 'not a proper/real/right' question culture doesn't help the site. Anyone should be able to ask a question and at least get the answer in the form of an answer or a duplicate flag. Q&A is for support after all.

Comment: @TimPost I always have to look that up by myself as well if I want to link to it. I always forget if it's `[mcve]` or `[mvce]` or ... .

Comment: @DanielJames You're missing the point. Basic research should be done before asking a question. If the answer is available after just a  minute of searching, then there is no point in asking it here, because it's covered elsewhere. You claim you did research, but I say whatever you did was not sufficient. If you search for "Stack Overflow mcve" it's among the top hits on any of the major search engines. If Stack Overflow was a repository of all information, regardless of research required, the scope would be too much to handle. I didn't vote to close, just downvoted due to lack of research.

Comment: @mason If you google "What does MCVE mean" you get a wide variety of results. Everything from Multimedia Collaborative Virtual Environments to an article about Timothy McVeigh. (sorry, tagged the wrong person initially)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy That is not how you should perform a web search. When you search for things, don't include unnecessary words. Stick to keywords. You might start with simply searching for "mcve". If that's giving a lot of results that seem unrelated, then you should narrow it down to the problem domain, such as "stack overflow mcve". Seriously - this is a basic Internet skill. For example, let's say I was at the gym and I saw the posted workout includes "TTB" and I have no idea what that means. I'll Google "ttb". I get a bunch of unrelated hits like "Tax and Trade Bureau" [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] and "Tedeschi Trucks Band". So the domain is too wide, so I'll narrow it to "ttb workout" and discover it's for a movement called Toes To Bar and from there I can get information about how to perform the movement. If you can't research an acronym on the Internet using this technique...well it's time for you to learn how.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - the top hit (ignoring Google's AI "Featured Snippet") **is** this site's definition of MCVE. In fact the *entire* page of 10 results are from here. Granted, this question and comments may have helped, but seriously, one *should* (nicely, but still should) help a person to properly use search engines. My site-specific search on Google for "What does MCVE mean site:stackoverflow.com" yields 27,100 results. Speaking for myself? I also transpose MCVE and MVCE and thus almost always need to link to the help page!

Comment: @dfd At least with Google, Bing and DuckDuckGo, searching for "stack overflow mvce" (with transposed letters) still gets you the site's definition for a MCVE.

Comment: The SO help pages comes up as first hit in Google for me. That being said, inventing weird acronyms isn't very helpful to anybody. Particularly true when it comes to programming. "Below is my MCVE with the MFC for MSVC."

Comment: @TimPost [for your amusement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313675/help-center-search-for-mcve-does-not-return-the-mcve-help-page) :)

Comment: I rarely (love to say never but then I'll be proven wrong) use the acronym *without* providing a link to the help page. (1) Anyone needing me to explain what it is because their question doesn't fit likely needs the link. (2) I certainly can't be the best resource for explaining it. So yes, while a pretty lame/confusing acronym, the best way to let someone know what it is - IMHO (hopefully we all know that acronym) - is to provide a link to it.

Comment: @mason As developers, we are far outside the norm of how most people use search engines. "what does mcve mean" is a perfectly valid and reasonable request, and exactly matches the title of this very question.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy No, looking up an acronym is the same whether you're a developer or not. The same technique I described above for searching TTB can be used for finding information about MCVE. All those extra words in your search query are noise words. You don't need "what", "does", "mean". As demonstrated by simply searching for "stack overflow mcve" or "ttb workout", you can find what you're looking for. Thus those noise words aren't needed. Work smarter, not harder. Those noise words are helpful for people, so they're fine in a question title, but not in a search query.

Comment: @TimPost No, it means you need to read the [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I'll note that you guys bothered to **make searchable** to avoid questions like this. -_-

Comment: @mason While you're correct that it's LIKELY to be the first search result for most people, you can't know that for sure, because search engine results are customized based on user history, location, and more.

Comment: @mason also, I think your assumption that there's only one correct way to use a search engine, and everyone must use that approach or be ignored is unrealistic at best.

Comment: @barbecue I didn't say it's the only correct way. If you want the best results, I have found my technique to work well. Really, use whatever technique you want as long as it's working for you. But clearly, if you couldn't find out what MCVE means on Stack Overflow without resorting to asking a question on Meta, then your research skills need improvement.

Comment: **M**obile **C**onstruction **V**ehicle **E**xtension

Comment: **"...you need to ask someone"**  We are ONE. We are the Borg. stackoverflow is an imperfect being. Lower your asininities. You will be assimilated.

Comment: By Grapthar's hammer! How many nits can we pick on this FLA? How about MCVE is an initialism, not an acronym.  It is therefore incumbent of every SO-er to downvote the preferred answer - discuss.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's an acronym (Stargateur [was kind enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean/367019#comment582505_366988) to point out the [help center article about it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - had I known that existed, I would have just linked to it):

- (**M**)inimal
- (**C**)omplete
- (**V**)erifiable
- (**E**)xample

It refers to the *least* amount of code required for someone to run the program on a stated architecture and be likely to reproduce the problem that's being described in the question.

Now *how* that's given can vary because languages treat dependencies in different ways. If your code depends on a static library (which might be proprietary), then you'd need to provide something to mock it, if it's not possible to isolate the code around it.

Likewise, if your code relies on dependency injection, you might need to provide a mock setter, or just annotate the code to indicate that you've eliminated that part as being problematic.

So "minimal" in some cases can actually be quite large, even with every effort given to offer only the code needed to reproduce an issue. It's in those cases where it's *really* likely that debugging prior to asking hasn't been done as optimally as possible, and help on how to diagnose the problem might be what's needed.

The term is expressed sort of eternally in an *ideal* sense, in hopes of guiding people to not paste their *entire project* into the body of the question - results vary from language to language.

In the best of outcomes, those that haven't fully optimized the example code to be as minimal as possible *are shown* how to better isolate problems using tools that they probably have. In the worst outcomes, the question is put on hold, and the user may or may not receive additional advice on how to debug, depending on how much time people have and how easily the chunk of code they did post can be processed.

In most cases, just indicating that you've done your best to post the minimum amount needed *and tested it* to see if the problem reproduces is enough to earn quite a bit of goodwill, and cause people to be more likely to help you further debug (which generally obviates the question anyway).

Comment: I'm glad to know I'm not the only one who has trouble keeping up with all of the platform changes.

Comment: In the context of data science-y languages like R/Python this will also often include some (minimal) representation of the data you're working with in addition to your code.

Comment: Acronyms always confuse me -- no matter how many times I look them up, there's always this momentary brain freeze when I encounter them. I  assumed MCVE was a variation of MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller) -- and I was still mentally trying to fit in the E. Can't we just use full words? Sure, it costs a few bytes and increases our carbon footprint, but so does this clarification.

Comment: Protip: If you use `[mcve]` in a comment, the system will automatically replace it with a full link (not just the acronym) to that page.

Comment: Terribly sorry to be that guy, but MCVE is not an acronym, it's an initialism. I wish it was an acronym, that certainly would have made it easier to remember.

Comment: Am I the only one who is frustratingly disappointed that our Director Of Community Strategy didn't know about one of the most commonly linked help pages that I'm pretty sure has been around longer than I've been a member (over half the time the Director has been a member)? *And* that they didn't bother to use the Help search function to check before answering?

Comment: Note that you can create a magic link in a comment to the help center page like this: `[mcve]`. (on the main site only)

Comment: And since OP seems to hang around front-end questions it might be wise to point them to StackSnippet which is of great help to show such an MCVE in these tags.

Comment: One could also mention *TeX - LaTeX's* awesome *[I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231)* (though it is *minimal working example* (MWE)).

Answer (score 19):

In context, MCVE is <s>still</s> duckspeak for "Please post code that I can run too which also shows me your error."

The main thing here that the acronym motivates is "Minimal" and "Complete".  **A code sample should be as *small* as possible while at the same time completely represents the error you're experiencing.**

That is to say, it makes no sense to post five or six different classes if your actual error is isolated to how you interact with two of them.

I feel like the answer you linked does convey that pretty clearly:

> The problem is that an MCVE is not defined by what it *is*, but rather what it should *do*: provide readers of the question with a **clear example** of your problem which leaves **no room for guesswork**.

If your example isn't clear, then it can't be considered an MCVE.   If your example requires some guesswork, it can't be considered an MCVE.

---

In the context of [the second question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366867/mcve-for-not-being-very-welcoming) you link, I largely...agree that it's been used more as duckspeak in many unnecessary cases where an MCVE has been mostly provided but it's not complete *enough*.  Worse, it's also utilized as a way to inflame or insult others for not doing *enough* to make their question perfect for Stack Overflow, which has its *own* way of putting people off from the site.  The spirit of the message - show us code that replicates your error - is lost from the overall mechanic of the message.

Comment: I think "I speak duck" needs to be on the back of a limited edition set of SO T shirts.

Comment: @TimPost:  Make it a hoodie and I'll throw cash at it *sight unseen*.

Comment: Sold, I'll take 20 @TimPost

Comment: And make sure it's that same duck from this year's April Fool's debugging help.

Comment: I miss the April Fool's Duck (though he was no fool)

Comment: More like *"the smallest, self-contained code that I can run too which also shows me your error."*