# Need tip reformulating question to follow (or show how it can't follow) the Minimum, verifiable example principle

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352309/weird-relation-error-configuring-ef-under-net-core-2) and got a tip that I should post a minimal example. I'm not sure how to do it and tried to explain why.

I agree that it's a great way to diagnose an issue but I'm not clear on how to apply that principle in this particular case. The suggestion received seem to more like a generic (and well-meant) advise rather than an actionable item.

Comment: The comment contains a link to the help center that goes into detail on what you need to be doing.   Start by reading it.  It contains *plenty* of actionable items, you just haven't acted on them.

Comment: Having experience with .NET Core and EFCore, it seems pretty reasonable to try to replicate the issue in an MCVE.

Comment: One would have hoped that after **800** questions you've have learned how to provide a reproducible code sample though, without needing to be prompted for it.

Comment: A quick check for the experts in .NET - given the information in the question, could anyone then motivate an attempt at a solution or is more information required?  What information is missing from the question which would make it then answerable?

Comment: @Makoto: Note, that at the point when the comment was asked, only the first code sample was present in the question.

Comment: @BDL:  And the comment chain *continued* to demand an MCVE without really being indicative of what's missing *after* more code was supplied.  So I'm just appealing to the .NET experts here on Meta to figure out what the question is missing.  I'm such a neophyte in .NET that I can't say for sure but on the surface, I'm not seeing much missing.  The experts can see what I can't so I'm hoping they'll actually shine a light here.

Comment: From what I can tell, that *should* work.  I'm not seeing any glaring errors in the EF code or schema.  An additional piece of information would be knowing exactly when the error occurs; at initialization,  or when attempting to traverse or populate the entities.

Comment: @fbueckert When I watch the things in the Watch window, I can see the structure there, right after I've used *SaveChanges()*. It seems to be properly connected. However, upon starting the application I get the strange error in the Stack Trace Explorer. And then we have the started but interrupted stuff in the browser.

Comment: This is likely where the MCVE would come in; a minimal dbContext, along with the classes, would likely be enough to try to replicate it.  The structure of your OnModelCreating is different than I'm familiar with, but I don't see it causing this issue.

Comment: @Servy As an experienced user and helping instance here on SO, would you be able to point out a few actual, specific and actionable items I could do to improve? Referring me to the material that I've seen numerous times, after my 800 questions here seems like a Catch 22 spot. Would you be able to point out something specific that I'd be able to do?

Comment: @fbueckert Interesting. I followed the form from the docs. What is that you do differently, please? Perhaps that can give a hint on what to do here.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You've been presented with *lots* of specific actionable items.  You've responded to that by asking other people to do it for you.   So my specific, actionable advice, is to follow the advice you've been given, which is quite a lot, rather than always asking other people to do it for you.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for your opinion. Regrettably, referring me back to something that I've already failed to gain from isn't very productive. I trust you did your best to help me. It hasn't been sufficient this time. During my 800 questions I've managed to provide a lot of good examples so I think I get the idea. This time, I cound't. It's not a matter of unwillingness but of inability. Prompting me to do so is pointless. Referring back to those prompting isn't of gain, neither as far I can understand. Thanks you for trying, though.

Comment: This is straying off of the meta topic, so I won't continue this beyond this comment.  My structure is basically lambdas for initialization.  It's not a huge change, so that was more an observation than a specific focus.  An MCVE would include a full dbContext for those classes, and perhaps your seed code, as well.  I can't guarantee I can spot it, but that is kind of the point of making an MCVE; to replicate the issue with as little code as possible.

Comment: @fbueckert Perhaps I'm asking the wrong way. I haven't argued against a need of MVCE. I was under the impression that posting a whole project on BitBucker or such was a no-no and that I had to put all the code needed in the question. Was I misstaken? I can make a minimal example and upload it and post a link to it. Is that a proper way here on SO, would you say?

Comment: Nope, definitely not.  The code needs to be contained in the question itself.  You've got some of it; the classes.  The process to replicating the issue should help narrow down the issue, perhaps to the point where you pinpoint it and no longer need support.  If not, well, then we've got a question where others can replicate your issue.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The proper way is to reproduce all code *in the question itself* necessary to reproduce the question. That means use as much code as necessary, but no more. The MCVE documentation explains this well.

Comment: @Servy Your comment about having higher expectations from someone who has been on the site so long really resonates with me. I've seen quite a few users with hundreds of questions that don't seem to understand some of the basics of how the site operates. I wonder how they got that way, and what can be done about it? I don't want to single people out, but at the same time I feel like *something* should be done. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @mason People who are able to ask acceptable questions, meaning they're able to create good MCVEs for their problems, accurately describe the problems they're having, and do adequate research to ensure the solutions to their problems aren't already readily accessible, are going to find the solution to their problem on their own the vast majority of the time.  The people who are asking questions constantly are consequently those who consistently don't do those things.  Anyone who practices the basics of how the site works isn't ever going to ask *that* many questions.

Comment: @Servy I agree. So taking that thought process a step further: if these users are probably a highly concentrated source of low quality questions (yet somehow they manage to get upvoted): is there some sort of change to the system we can make to slow them down and force them to provide higher quality questions? Should a moderator get involved and tell them that they need to put more thought/effort into their questions before they'll be allowed to post more questions? Should there be some sort of rate limit? I'm just brainstorming, because I feel this situation isn't ideal.

Comment: @mason The mechanism that's *supposed* to deal with that problem is the post ban, but it has numerous problems.  One being that just a small number of questions that "go viral" will offset many dozens, if not more, of bad questions, so when a very simple "copy the documentation" question becomes a high search result for that common problem, the user becomes immune to the post ban for quite some time.  Get lucky again once in the next several dozen questions asked, and the cycle repeats. Next is that it relies on people actually downvoting/close voting bad questions, which they don't always do.

Comment: @mason Technically moderators are *allowed* to step in in such cases, although in my experience they very rarely actually do so, even when merited.

Comment: @Servy Right, so the system is broken. I feel like we need a more radical alternative. I've actually thought about this problem for a while (I call them "perennial question askers" in my head, for want of a better term). But I haven't come up with any ideas I feel like are good enough, so I haven't brought it up on Meta before.

Comment: After the back and forth that has happened here and in the question itself, I'm firmly convinced that not only is an MCVE possible, but absolutely *required* to properly debug this issue.  This scenario is a poster child for exactly why we require one in the question itself, and that askers need to put in the effort to make it happen if they want support.  I'm not convinced this could have been solved without one.

Comment: @mason I almost feel tempted not to point something out here because of fear of causing irritation and being again misinterpreted. Please accept my apology if the following causes any annoyance etc. You've mentioned "*yet somehow they manage to get upvoted*" and I'd like to point out the assumption you're making here - namely that such questions **indeed are** of low quality. That's definitely a cause for surprise. However, what if those users' question hold good quality (as defined by the consensus of the community, which is how this site operates)? It's possible if you're open to the idea...

Comment: @mason ...that your judgement skills are off and that **your opinion** doesn't align with the community's opinion. Not saying that you're wrong. I'm just using the way the site operates - it's **comunity driven**, not **driven by a few (skilled and devoted) users**. In such case, there's no reason for surprise. It's just that you misjudged the quality of a portion of those questions.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sure, it's possible to ask hundreds of good questions. But I just don't think it's likely. In fact, I think it's highly unlikely someone is going to up with more than a couple dozen good questions in a single year. If that, probably a dozen is more reasonable. As Servy said, people who do adequate research and take the time to come up with an MCVE are just not likely have to have that many questions to ask.

Comment: @fbueckert I've reflected on the question and comments too. I arrived at a different conclusion. I still maintain that I can't, despite trying and reading, post just the code to provide a MCV example. And as I suggested elsewhere - whoever claims that it's possible is urged to prove it, instead of arguing it, so I can be educated. Until then, it's their opinion against others' opinion and nothing more. I will gladly stand corrected on this one. Also, it turned out that it could be resolved based on the original sample assuming that the reader was aware of that issue from their experience.

Comment: So prove it.  Show us where the problem was, in the question itself.  You have yet to do so, despite many requests.  Chances are going to be *extremely* good that you missed something critical, and is exactly why we needed an MCVE in the *first* place.  Just saying everything was there doesn't actually support your case, as you're not backing it up.  The proof for requiring an MCVE is in these very comments and discussion; *nobody can reproduce your issue*.

Comment: @mason I agree with you partly. However, I strongly disagree with the attitude tat Servy exhibits as I find it accusative, whiny and elitistic. You can't imagine how provoking it feels when I'm doing my best and really do the research for a long time just to be shot down based on an assumption that I'm horsing around. I share the view that we need to do something about low quality questions/answers. But I strongly feel that something needs to be done about the low quality of reception. My motto: if you're too frustrated to be friendly and pleasant, be silent and do not engage. My opinion only.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It appears to me that Servy was expressing his opinion professionally. Now you may dislike that opinion, because it has negative implications for you. That doesn't mean that he was unfriendly or unpleasant. I think everyone here has been very friendly and pleasant, and *especially patient*.

Comment: @fbueckert Two things. (a) I can't prove a non-fact. Whoever claims it's possible to post code to MCVE without a link to an external repo needs to prove that it's possible. Simply reiterating your **opinion** that it **can** be done seems pointless. (b) I've already pointed out what the problem was and linked to a site that explains it. Please check the comments from yesterday. I hope it's clear enough although very weird an unexpected. Thank you for the follow up, though.

Comment: a) @mason provided an example gist of what, exactly, an MCVE can look like, *using your own code*.  That's how you do it.  You copy it into your question, so people don't have to jump through hoops just to help you.  I even ran that myself, and could not reproduce your error.  b) I've been looking, but I can't see any comment from you that says what the issue was.  All I see is, "This was solved", both here and in your question.  Mind pointing me to where you've actually explained it?

Comment: (1/2) @KonradViltersten No, we don't need to prove that an MCVE is possible. The onus is on you to prove that it isn't, since you're the one that asked the question in the first place. And no, you haven't pointed out what the problem was. I got a specific error while trying to run your code. You addressed why I got that error. But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the *original problem* that you stated. This is where having an MCVE come in handy.

Comment: (2/2) However, I don't think an entire web application is necessary to reproduce your issue. Your problem was with Entity Framework, not ASP.NET. Therefore you should be able to produce the issue in a console application. We've tried giving you all sorts of hints at how to accomplish this. But you seem more intent on arguing why you shouldn't have to provide us with an MCVE rather than taking the time to come up with an MCVE. Did you read [Nicol's excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379423/1139830)?

Comment: @mason I found most of hte replies friendly, yet. However a comment about the 800 posts and an subjective expectation sounded to me rather accusative. As it turned out, the code posted **was** indeed enough (although very hard to see it if one hasn't had that issue before, really weird issue). I've seen other posts by Servy and I disagree with his formulations (not only directed at me). I do trust he's got the best intentions and I'm sure his very skilled. However, I don't feel that he contributes to a good atmosphere on the site. I'm not the only one neither. But I don't want to whine back.:)

Comment: @KonradViltersten The code you provided in the question *not* enough. It couldn't reproduce the issue, so it wasn't Verifiable. It wasn't Complete, as I couldn't drop it into an app and run it. And it wasn't Minimal, as it contained code unnecessary to the issue at hand.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I'd say that you not being able to reproduce the issue based on the gist he provided is kind of an implication that it's not a MCVE. So it kind of proves my point, doesn't it? I claim that I can't (don't know how to) post MCVE. As for the issue - there's a link in that comment as well. Perhaps it's not that obvious - sorry about that. Apparently, the issue went poof and disappeared when I switched from underscore to a letter in my lambda expressions. (Yes, I do hear how insane it sounds, hence the link, there.) And since the underscore was present in the original code...

Comment: @KonradViltersten My Gist was an example of what an MCVE might look like. It wasn't supposed to reproduce your problem. If I could reproduce your problem, we wouldn't be here having this conversation! I don't understand how you can't understand this. Since you've been on Stack Overflow, you've asked an average of 2.33 questions per week, over a 6.5 year span. It's vital that you understand the points that we're making to you here, in order to keep the quality of content on the site up to our standards.

Comment: Considering his example MCVE was made from your code, you're proving our point that it was not an MCVE.  And if the lambda underscore was the issue, then why didn't it occur with said MCVE?  You *have* to be able to reproduce the issue, reliably.  Since nobody but you could reproduce the issue, even with an attempted MCVE, that means *you missed something*.  There's something in your specific configuration that is critical to the issue.  Something you *haven't* told us, and an MCVE would bring to light.

Comment: @mason It's logically impossible to prove an non-fact. And I'm not saying that anybody needs to prove that it's possible. You misunderstood me there. I'm saying that simply stating *oh, it can be done*, is **ones opinion**, not a fact. I can state the opposite having the same strength of proof (namely none). It's my responsibility to provide MCVE - I agree on that. That doesn't imply that it's possible, let alone that I know how to do it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The biggest concern to me is: how can you not know how to produce an MCVE? You've read the documentation, you've had many comments explaining it, and you've got Nicol's answer down below. You *can* follow those steps to produce an MCVE in this situation. You might think it's an opinion, but it's based on years of experience on Stack Overflow and professional software development and education.

Comment: @mason That's also a thing that confuses me.  That's...part of the basic troubleshooting process; reproduce, isolate, resolve.  An actual MCVE is usually more involved than you need, but the process to finding it should be part of a programmer's core skillset.

Comment: @mason I do respect that you **think** it's not needed. You might even be right. But it's still an opinion. And as far I could observe, I got the problem when serving from a controller but not when i did it from a console app. And I might very well be wrong and have missed something. The only thing I'm sure of is that **stating** it can be done doesn't constitute a proof that it can. Explaining what MCVE is doesn't prove that neither. I know that you tried to help but I wasn't able to improve based on the information presented despite trying to. regrettably.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It doesn't *have* to be a console application. A web application MCVE is acceptable too, though not as ideal. But you weren't even able to provide us with a web application that reproduced the issue. If it takes a web application, so be it. Put all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue *in your question*. If you're able to create a reproducible example as web application, I will gladly take that and either edit it into a console app that still reproduces the issue, or I will admit that a web application is necessary.

Comment: @mason You seem to be mistaken on a specific part. I **do know** how to create **a** MCVE. I'm not sure how to create one **for this case**. I know how to cook a dish. But I might be confused how to cook a specific dish. And the issue turned out to be really weird, that's true.

Comment: @mason Are you actually saying that I (in some extremely rare cases) might have to post PROJ files and such? I mean, certain configs might be there etc. That seems like a bridge too far...

Comment: @KonradViltersten You're able to reproduce the issue in your application. You say the code in your question is enough to reproduce. Those two facts should allow you to use the techniques described by the [MCVE] documentation and further explained by Nicol's answer and numerous comments to actually come up with an MCVE. You really can't use the excuse that you don't know how. You've been told how. You just need to *do it*. And you need to provide the solution to your question, something that you've been asked for multiple times but have yet to provide, though you state you have a solution.

Comment: *Usually* a proj file isn't necessary. If you look at my Gist, I omitted that because anyone could create a new .NET Core app, quickly add the required NuGet packages, and run my code. But if it does turn out to be necessary for your example, then you should include it. You can determine if it's necessary by looking at the MCVE documentation and following the advice in Nicol's answer.

Comment: I never said that the code was enough to **reproduce**. I said it was enough to answer **if the reader had right knowledge**. Now, since the issue was really weird, you were ignorant of that the underscore in the lambdas might cause problems when hosted under .NET Core (kind of). I posted the solution as a comment because I'm hoping that someone more skilled might have even better input on that. Perhaps I should post an answer myself. What do you think?

Comment: You are wrong.  **The question does not have enough information to reproduce the issue**.  I'm not an expert with .NET Core, or EF, but I can say I've used them both for quite some time.  I have the right knowledge.  Critically, an attempt at an MCVE **did not reproduce the error**.

Comment: @mason BTW, I wrote "*ignorant*" as in "*not knowing/aware of a certain aspect*". I want to have this stated because in some languages, that word is regarded as diminishing implying that the subject is of low knowledge or skill level in general. That's not what I try to say.

Comment: @KonradViltersten But you were able to reproduce the issue, in your application, right? Otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question in the first place? The fact that you say you can do that means that an MCVE is possible, and that the MCVE documentation and Nicol's answer are enough information to help you come up with one. The underscore lambda turned out to be a *side issue* I got when trying to use your code to reproduce the issue. It doesn't answer why you got the original error, which was `Cannot create a relationship between because there already is a relationship between .....`

Comment: @fbueckert I never said the original code was enough to **reproduce** the error. I only wrote that it was sufficient to a non-ignorant reader to spot the error. It's just you have not that knowledge (which is expected because the issue is weird). And I noticed after more laborations that it's also have to do with diffenrt version of the framework and other stuff. Rather hard to post "just code".

Comment: @KonradViltersten No one asked you to post just code. If a specific version of certain frameworks is required to reproduce, then *state that*. If specific seed data is necessary to reproduce, then *include that*. I feel like we've told you this several times already, and you're just asking us to repeat ourselves at this point.

Comment: There seems to be more argument about why you can't make an MCVE than just going through the exercise.  At this point, I'm writing this off.  The question is useless to future readers without an MCVE, and should be closed and deleted.

Comment: @mason The underscore was **the** issue, not a side issue. It's just that it comes up in certain version combinations of the packages only. And again - I'm saying that I can't (don't know how to) create MCVE based on the provided help. Perhaps I'm not bright enough or maybe I'm misreading someting. Not sure. But until I see an example of how to do it in this particular case, I feel that I can't improve it, regrettably. Probably it's better to drop it in order not to cause bad atmosphere. Thanks guys for trying. There will be other occasions.   :)

Comment: If the underscore was indeed the issue, then great! What's to stop you from following Nicol's advice now? And why haven't you posted the answer *on your question*?

Comment: @fbueckert Please feel free to vote to delete/close the question if you see that fit. That's the correct modus operandi of the site. I'm not sure if it's of gain to others as well. I was helped by the "*there's issue with _, don't use them*" comment. No MCVE in there but maybe I'll give it another whack tomorrow. Sorry if I caused bad emotions.

Comment: @KonradViltersten If using underscores in your EF lambdas is indeed the issue, I'd definitely say that has value for future users.

Comment: @mason I agree with fbuecket that the issue's been exhausted now and everthing that could be said has been stated already. I thank everybody for the input and take it into consideration for the future.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You still haven't responded: why can't you follow Nicol's advice to create an MCVE, and why haven't you posted an answer yet? You also haven't answered his comment on his answer.

Comment: @mason Thank you for the follow-up. I feel that I have answered why I can't follow his advice. I see that I have explained why I'm reluctant to post the answer myself and also that I responded to the comment. A certain pause was called for, in my opinion, so I went out to deliver food to the local homeless shelter as I do every Friday around 20:00. My apology for not responding immediately as well as not being able to reach you with the answers to your questions.

Comment: @mason I guess the embarrassingly large amount of comments might make the reply less apparent. At any rate, I feel that I've said what I had to say and there's no point reiterating it. Either there's no interest on the recipient side or I'm unable to make my point sufficiently clear. One way or another, I feel that there's much better use of your time and effort than dwelling on this issue - there are questions posted by other people that also require the attention. I can't monopolize the community like this.

Comment: I think this is an important issue: we have a user that has asked nearly 800 questions that doesn't know how to go about creating a MCVE (yes, I know you claim to know how, but the truth is if you knew how, you would have done so). Giving up and asking everyone to move on isn't a good solution. We're just going to be running into more conflicts soon.

Comment: @mason The problem I have discussing this matter is that you got stuck on the (incorrect) implication that knowing how to create a MCVE means being able to do so in any situation regardless of the circumstances. I agree that it's not a good solution to just move on. However, given how I perceive the situation, the alternative is even worse. I'm sorry to say that I find certain comments less than constructive. I hope we won't run into collisions in the future but that's your responsibility to see that it doesn't happen as much as mine. Being civilized and backing off is a part of it. So I do.

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, I never claimed it's possible to create a MCVE in all circumstances. Obviously there are situations where the system is too complex or dependent on hard to control things where an MCVE just isn't possible. But in this particular case, it sounds like a very easy to reproduce problem. It's simply Entity Framework, and you're able to consistently reproduce it in your web application. Converting that to a MCVE should be *easy*, and converting it to a console app after that shouldn't be much more work. Actually, a console app may be easier.

Comment: @mason I understand it's your firm opinion based on experience and analysis of the problem. I have a different opinion based on the observations from this particular case. I have tried to point out certain circumstances (e.g. the fact that **wasn't** reproducible in a console) but I see that I'm not reaching you. I'm not sure if I missed something or not but I'm sure that it's tiresome to have to reiterate the same statements over and over again. Since those collide with your opinion, I see no way to get further unless you invite the option that things are different than what you expect.

Comment: @mason I don't want you to feel ignored or dismissed but I realize that it's a bit late and I have to work at the church tomorrow morning so I'd need to hit the pillows. I doubt we can get to anything constructive at this point, regrettably. Wishing you a nice evening and hoping that it's going to be a non-issue in the future, mate.

Answer (score 6):

There really aren't "tips" we can give for making an MCVE. It's really all spelled out in the name. So do that.

Pretend you don't have access to your project, and everything you have access to is what you put into your question. Copy it into a new, empty project and run it. Does it run? If not, then it is not **Complete**; add stuff from your actual project (not just code, but data files, external library names/versions that it relies on, build options, etc) to your question until this process can be executed successfully.

Now that it is Complete, attempt to reproduce the bug. Can you reproduce the bug? If not, then it is not **Verifiable**. Add whatever is missing until you can reproduce the bug. This may include command-like data, external data files, or whatever.

Lastly, remove some stuff from your code and/or data files, either at random or based on what you think *isn't* the source of the problem. Is the bug still happening? If the bug stopped happening, put that stuff back and remove something else. If the bug is still happening, keep that stuff removed and then repeat this process by removing more stuff. Continue iterating on this until you cannot remove *anything* without affecting whether the bug is still happening. Now, your example is **Minimal**.

And as a side effect, you probably now know where the bug is and what is causing it, so you don't need to ask your question at all.

Comment: Just as a followup to your last sentence: once you've created that MCVE and in the process of doing so discovered and fixed the issue, the next step is to think about whether it'd be useful for others to see the MCVE and the solution. If it is, it can be posted on Stack Overflow. It will likely help someone else, which you can feel good about, and you'll get some reputation points, if that's something you care about.

Comment: @mason Assuming you've done your research and solutions to the described problem aren't already readily accessible.  Which, for common, and most uncommon problems, there probably already is a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We seem to get stuck on the explanation of wat MCVE is. That's been extensively pointed out, discussed and linked to. I was aware of the definition and links since before. Still, I wan't able to make it happen. Not because I don't know what MCVE is and not because I question the value of it. Hence, the question on tips on how to make it in this particular case. I understand how to create **a** MCVE. I'm not sure how to create one **in this case**.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: But what is *special* about your case that prevents that? What *in particular* makes it difficult to provide completeness, verifiability, and/or minimality? And which ones of these are giving you problems?

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for the follow-up. Regrettably, I fel that the whole issue got too infected and I'm worried that pursuing it further will cause more displaeasure than gain. I've noticed on numerous occasions that there were arguments against something I didn't say and I sense that there's such a deep rooted pre-determination behind the help offered that it's not possible to see what I'm trying to get across. The whole thing has spawned 50+ comments  and I sense that it's only with a considerable effort that we keep it civilized (myself included in the effort required not to get snorky).

Answer (score -10):

The problem I have with this comment chain (as is my wont to just dislike comments anyway) is that there's no clarity in what's actually *missing* from your question.

The comments kite the question.

[image]

The real issue I take with this is, given that I'm about as useful to you when it comes to .NET as you would be with servicing my car*, I can't say imperatively what's wrong with the question.

To me, that makes the comments unnecessary. You've now supplied more information pursuant to an MCVE with your recent revision, and any further comments demanding that to effect are no longer necessary or unhelpful, and should be flagged for removal as such.

<sup>*: Maybe you *could* service cars; I'm just forbidden to myself by EULA.</sup>

Comment: There simply isn't an MCVE in the question. It's not complete. I don't have enough to drop into an application and run it. And when I [tried to create an example of what an MCVE might look similar to](https://gist.github.com/mason-mcglothlin/e23abd02fbb62f32caab10961d0d98e3) I wasn't able to get the error in the message. Meaning the code in the question isn't Complete, thus it isn't an MCVE. I'm trying to provide as much detail in the comments as I can to assist in coming up with an MCVE, but at some point the onus is on the asker to actually reproduce the problem!

Comment: I'm with @mason on this one; there's not enough there to reproduce the issue.  I've got a feeling the issue is somewhere in the dbContext, but all we have from there is a single method.  I think an MCVE is not only possible, but required.

Comment: @fbueckert Exactly. There's some config or seed data or both missing in order to repro the issue. Without it, we're left guessing. If the asker is able to reproduce the error in their web app, it shouldn't be that difficult to extract out the conditions, by following the MCVE documentation. I don't think what I've been asking for is impossible, and I'm trying to educate on how to ask a proper question in the process.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm going on a limb here and will prepare a link with the runnable minimal version of the misbehavior. It's going to be really awkward if I'll get the suggestion of not posting external links, hehe. Give me 10 minutes, please.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Why should it be awkward? I'd be perfectly happy if you had something similar to [my gist](https://gist.github.com/mason-mcglothlin/e23abd02fbb62f32caab10961d0d98e3) in your question. Would probably even upvote it. Of course, it's gotta reproduce the error, and not have anything unnecessary in it.

Comment: @mason Sure thing, mate. Give me a few minutes to upload the stuff and clean off everything again (I've been doing the minimal version all day long todayI. Perhaps the community will see something I've missed, then.

Comment: @makoto Your answer here says "supplied more information pursuant to an MCVE" but the key point is that just adding additional information doesn't make it an MCVE, or even a CVE. It might be a step in the right direction, but that's not enough. Thus I used comments to help clarify what we're looking for. You say you don't like comments, but I don't understand why you would say that. Without comments, it's unlikely we'd get enough information in the question to actually provide a valid answer. Someone experienced with EF Core might be able to (I only have a basic understanding) but most can't.

Comment: I don't want to leave Konrad stranded with no solution. If you've got a better idea on how to, without using comments 1) teach users to make an MCVE when they're not grokking it and 2) explain what's missing from a question to create an MCVE, I'm all ears. I agree there's more comments than there should be, and I don't mind cleaning them away once we actually have an MCVE. But for now, I think they're valuable to the asker as they're trying to figure out the MCVE process.

Comment: @mason:  You're relying on the phrase "MCVE" as if that conveys everything that needs to be conveyed.  Had you told the OP that they were missing X, Y or Z detail, then that would be far more beneficial than the acronym we use.  I have no choice *but* to bow to your superior knowledge of .NET, but in situations like this when someone is missing some details, I don't go out of my way to say "include an MCVE"; I usually say, "What does X component look like?  How is Y set up?  What was the error message?"

Comment: @mason:  Don't let the fact that you're looking for an MCVE blind you to the *intent* of the MCVE.  If you're wanting to help then the comments you're asking are tacit, insightful and to the point of solving the problem.  Just saying "give me an MCVE" isn't solving the problem.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I don't disagree then but the comments weren't really helping the circumstance.  If you had commented something to that effect on the original post, I would have no qualms with such a request.  Something that's at least motivating the solution as opposed to parroting policy is better in my eyes.

Comment: @Makoto My original comment requested an MCVE, there wasn't much code in the post at the time. In my opinion, anyone that read the description of MCVE and knows a little bit about .NET should understand that the code in the question at the time was neither minimal, nor complete. The MCVE documentation explains how to make things both minimal and complete. So I don't think reminding someone to provide a MCVE and linking to the documentation is unhelpful. As more attempts were made, I pointed outed specific things that the question was lacking, as well as specific things that were extraneous.

Comment: I think I disagree there @mason; from the comment chain it *genuinely* reads like you're just barking policy.  I realize you probably weren't meaning to, but I don't see any comment which actually asks questions of the OP in spite of the fact that they were lacking code.  It's reasonable to ask for the MCVE once - because it *did* lack that, this is not in contest - but even after more code was supplied, I never got the impression that you were motivating a solution to the question more than you were concerned with the hygiene of the question itself.

Comment: (1/2) @Makoto Several times I was responding to specific comments asking about what an MCVE is. So of course I'm going to respond with something that sounds like policy or a dictionary definition. I even answered with describing specific things that were missing, such as the DbContext,  and explaining what isn't necessary (the JSON configuration and MVC setup).

Comment: (2/2) I can't tell someone exactly what to put in to make it an MCVE because I'm *unable to reproduce the problem*. That's the asker's responsibility. I can however point out things that make it not meet MCVE requirements and describe in general what we're looking for.

Comment: If someone says "this code doesn't reproduce the issue" it doesn't make sense to then ask "what would it need to reproduce the issue?". I don't know! That's why I'm asking for it! I can get by without a MCVE, but I really do need a CVE in order to have an answerable question.

Comment: @mason:  [Peruse an earlier discussion about MCVEs in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367021/1079354) and see if you arrive at a similar conclusion.  I stand firm in my assertion that you're missing the forest for the trees on this one, and you were more obsessed with the MCVE than actually addressing the problem.  You can ask clarifying questions without the need for the acronym, and if you're struggling with how to do *that*, then I'm really not sure what else can equip you besides...ask questions about the *question*.

Comment: @Makoto I did ask questions about the question. The whole point obtaining a CVE or MCVE is so that we can answer the question. Maybe you're missing this because you aren't familiar with .NET. The question as asked, and as it still stands, does not have enough information to reproduce the issue. Someone familiar with that particular error message might be able to assist. Perhaps they know some specific config or seed necessary that would lead to the question, or perhaps there's a bug in the framework. But we can't know *for sure* what's wrong in this situation until the question is complete.

Comment: No one's answered the question I posed earlier in the Meta discussion - *what* makes it incomplete?  What is lacking?  Why can't a comment address that piece specifically? What are you missing as a .NET expert which would make this question answerable?  In my mind, *that's* how you should be framing the request for the MCVE, @mason.  Then there can be no ambiguity in how your comment is meant to be interpreted; you're *clearly* asking about the question and you're *clearly* motivating solutions for it as opposed to there being any doubt.

Comment: @Makoto Again, that's not a valid question to ask me. All I can say is that it *does not reproduce the issue*. Something else is needed. If I knew what that something else was, I wouldn't have to ask! I can speculate that the question is missing config code or some sort of seed condition. And I did suggest those things.

Comment: @Makoto I did answer that, to a degree; I said we needed the full dbContext.  Without having more information, though, there's no way to *know* what else we need.  That's kind of the point of going through the exercise of creating an MCVE; so that answerers don't have to guess what's wrong, or try to pull non-existent information from the asker.  It's all right there, in the code.